# List comprehension to extract multiple fields from list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples, python-itertools

I have a list of tuples

```
servers = [('server1', 80 , 1, 2), ('server2', 443, 3, 4)]
```

I want to create a new list that only has the first two fields   as in:

```
 [('server1', 80), ('server2', 443)]
```

but I cannot see how to craft a list comprehension for more than one element.

```
hosts = [x[0] for x in servers]  # this works to give me ['server1', server2']

hostswithports = [x[0], x[1] for x in servers] # this does not work
```

I prefer to learn the pythonic way vs using a loop - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *loops are pythonic*

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

```
>>> servers = [('server1', 80 , 1, 2), ('server2', 443, 3, 4)]
>>> [(server, port) for server, port, *_ in servers]
[('server1', 80), ('server2', 443)]
```

Using `_` as a throwaway placeholder-name is a common convention.

Comment: This is the only one that, by only looking at the line in question, I have any idea what is happening. Readability matters: +1

Comment: ... and for older versions, `[(server, port) for server, port, _, _ in servers]` works just as well.

Comment: @tobias_k it is worth noting it handles things differently: `a, b, *_` will accept elements with at least two sub-elements. `a, b, _, _` only accepts elements with 4 sub-elements. So they are different in how they handle data that doesn't conform to the example. But with conforming data, they are the same... and in Py2.7 you don't get the choice ;)

Comment: I see I was just missing enclosing parentheses but I really like the readability of this approach

Comment: @TemporalWolf Of course, I thought that was clear, but you are right: OP actually never says anything about the shape of the lists, just that the first two elements are needed, so it might indeed be irregular.

Answer (score 18):

What you were doing was *almost* right. You were attempting to translate each tuple in your list into a new tuple. But you forgot to actually declare the tuple. That's what the parentheses are doing:

```
hosts = [(x[0], x[1]) for x in servers]
```

Comment: Thanks - I could have sworn I tried that too but obviously I did not!

Comment: @Bill If I had a nickel for every time I did that . . . I'd be able to buy a steak dinner at least

Answer (score 17):

Using basic slicing, which has the benefit of not failing if any of your list elements don't have the expected number of sub-elements.

```
[el[:2] for el in servers]
```

```
[('server1', 80), ('server2', 443)]
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter


servers = [('server1', 80 , 1, 2), ('server2', 443, 3, 4)]

result = list(map(itemgetter(0, 1), servers))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[('server1', 80), ('server2', 443)]
```

A more readable alternative is the following:

```
from operator import itemgetter

get_server_and_port = itemgetter(0, 1)
servers = [('server1', 80, 1, 2), ('server2', 443, 3, 4)]
result = [get_server_and_port(e) for e in servers]

print(result)  # [('server1', 80), ('server2', 443)]
```

Comment: Instead of a list generator based on “identity” transformation you could simply call the list constructor on the iterable `map` object:  `result = list(map(itemgetter(0, 1), servers))`. Otherwise +1 for the smart use of `itemgetter`.

Comment: An minor alternative would be to pass a slice object to itemgetter: `itemgetter(slice(n))` is equivalent to `itemgetter(0, 1, 2, ..., n-1)` in case you want to select a non-trivially sized index range. You can call the slice constructor with 2 or 3 arguments for ranges starting after the first element or ranges that skip indices respectively like with subscript slice expressions (`foo[start : stop : step]`).